# interlinking php-xml-html in anchor onclick

Tags: php, html, xml

I've a link like

```
<a href="hhh.html" onclick="bbb.php">the link</a>
```

the task is ... on clicking 'the link',  bbb.php has to go an url and process some data and generate some xxx.xml from which contents are to be loaded into hhh.html.

I've everything working but I want your suggestion that how to interlink the things with in single click.

I've used a javascript to achive the task but this is not working

```
<li><a href="link.html" onClick="loadphp();">the link</a></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadphp() {
    $.get("bbb.php");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

it is directly displaying the link page without processing php code 
...
at the same time I've tried kuboslav's way, even it is not working...
*after php is processed then it has to load html*...
I've checked with onclick include php bt it is also not working

Comment: `onclick` accepts javascript code, not a file name

Comment: @Shvelo thanks. for understanding purpose I've framed so. moreover I've no idea of hw 2 achieve it, hence i came for suggestions from people like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<a href="bbb.php">the Link</a>
```

And at the end of your `bbb.php` file add

```php
header ( 'Location: http://www.youriste.com/hhh.html', false, 302 );
```

Comment: did in the same way as suggested by you but it says `( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING ` in the line where I've added header